# What method can be used to write to a file from a custom keyboard?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, keylogger

Goal: Create a custom keyboard that logs all keystrokes to a local log file

I do already have a working keyboard now -- so that's done. I've verified the keyboard itself runs on my test device (Motorola Moto G, 4.1, hardware).

The problem is this: what methods might one use to write keystrokes to a log file?

So far, my research has lead me to this conclusion: The key logging functionality should (at least in part) go in the onKey method of the soft keyboard main java file.

I have already added the commitText and sendKeyEvent methods within onKey -- those are necessary for base keyboard functionality. Any ideas about what methods to put in there to log the keystrokes to a log file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the documentation about writing to files, that google provided:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

example code:

```
String filename = "keystrokes.log";
String data = "ActualKeyStroke";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`openFileOutput` is a method from [Context class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) which is the parent for
[InputMethodService (doc)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html)

Comment: First, thank you, that's a very thorough and well formatted answer. I think what's tripping me up isn't saving data to a log file, but the aspect of how to capture the keystrokes in the onKey method. I don't even know if it's possible, but it seems like it should be. In your example above, "ActualKeyStroke" is what I'm after. How can the current character code for the key currently being pressed be set to an ActualKeyStroke (or whatever) variable and then the value of that variable appended as a string to a keystrokes.log file? Or is that not the way to go about it?

Comment: onKeyDown(int notUnicodeKeyCode,KeyEvent event){
int unicodeCharPressed = event.getUnicodeChar();
} then store somewhere theese ints or convert them to string, and in time interval or at specific action for example - hidding keyboard -> write them to file (opening getting char and writing and closing file for INDIVIDUAL character is a bad design : ) so you can have StringBuilder as your class member and append the ints to it. For Finding good time to write to file see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html)